# How do I get the number of rows with Hibernate Criteria queries using MySQL 5?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rowcount, hibernate3

We've been using HQL mostly.  But we have this complex search form that contains many joins so I thought I would try my luck at using Criteria's (never have before).  I like the syntax much better and it fits the complex form we have.

My first instinct was to do a `.list().size()` BEFORE I applied the `setMaxResults` and `setFirstResult`.  Which of course is slow and lazy and a total resource hog.

After a little Googling I found an example that uses ScrollableResults.  But the post said that MySQL doesn't support cursors.  This was a post from 2004.  Here in 2012, we use MySQL 5 with InnoDB tables.  So I think we support cursors.  Then I found to use projections.

So not being a Hibernate guru, I'm lost on the best way.  We **MIGHT** use DB2 in the future so I would imagine whatever solution I use it would have to work in DB2 and MySQL 5.

Any ideas?  I guess at the minimum I could use a custom HQL to get a count(*).

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I just put this in:

```
ScrollableResults scr = crit.scroll();
scr.last();
int rowCount = scr.getRowNumber() + 1;
```

**vs**

```
int rowCount = crit.list().size();
```

Both before I put my limit/start values.  It ran MUCH faster.  So I'm assuming the cursor is working for out particular DB and results.  I even put some joins in there and it seems to still be much faster.

Any input on if this is still a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Criteria's `setProjection(Projections.property("id"))`.

Answer (score 1):

**I think getting the count through a separate query is the only option,** if you want to apply pagination by using `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults`.

Comment: What if the DB2 option was off the table?  Would the answer change then?  Thanks

Comment: My answer is based on the hibernate not on the database. Please note: Hibernate supports Lazy collections with batch size, which will serve your need little differently i.e. define batch size as your page size and entire collection as once. It will just lazily initialize them and when you iterate, it will load the results in batch.

Answer (score 0):

For sure `crit.list().size()` will load the full set of rows as entities in Hibernate session.

The method `ScrollableResults.last()` depends on JDBC driver implementation and it may be really slow too because the full `ResultSet` may be loaded completely, even if Hibernate entities are not created yet.

The best option is to use `crit.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult()`

Answer (score 0):

And you can include `hashcode()` in your code, that is,

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult().hashCode()
```